Query Multiple Named Ranges but don't include blank cells
I have a Google Sheets Formula that is combining data from 15 named ranges as follows;
=UNIQUE({USMTD; UKMTD; DEMTD; JPMTD; FRMTD; ITMTD; ESMTD; CAMTD; MXMTD; ANZMTD; BRMTD; COMTD; CLMTD; ARMTD; INMTD})

However the output has a blank row after every range (example shown below);
Black Row Example
I browsed through Stack Overview and came across a few posts, including;
Spreadsheets get unique names but ignore blank cells
But when I change the formula as suggested in an answer in the above link to;
=UNIQUE(FILTER({USMTD; UKMTD; DEMTD; JPMTD; FRMTD; ITMTD; ESMTD; CAMTD; MXMTD; ANZMTD; BRMTD; COMTD; CLMTD; ARMTD; INMTD},{USMTD; UKMTD; DEMTD; JPMTD; FRMTD; ITMTD; ESMTD; CAMTD; MXMTD; ANZMTD; BRMTD; COMTD; CLMTD; ARMTD; INMTD})<>"")

I then get an error message:
Error
FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.
Is there another way to remove the blank rows / cells with my named ranges?
Thanks in advance

You can try a QUERY() formula.
How about something like this?
=UNIQUE(QUERY({USMTD; UKMTD; DEMTD; JPMTD; FRMTD; ITMTD; ESMTD; CAMTD; MXMTD; ANZMTD; BRMTD; COMTD; CLMTD; ARMTD; INMTD},"Select * where Col1 is not null")


That doesn't work either, I get the following Error Message: Function QUERY parameter 3 expects number values. But 'Select * where Col1 is not null' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Sorry, I made a mistake when copying your formula over.  I have amended it.  Could you try it again?
